# How do I merge or attach a characteristic when the key I'm merging on isn't unique?

Tags: python

I have two different CSVs with different information that I need. The first has an account number, a ticker (mutual funds), and a dollar amount. The second has a list of Tickers and their classification (Stock, bond, etc.) I want to merge the two on the Ticker so that I have the account number, Ticker, classification, and dollar amount all together. Several of the account numbers hold the same funds, meaning the ticker will be used multiple times. When I try merging I get rows that duplicate and a lot of missing information.

I tried merging with inner and on the left. I tried making the second CSV a dictionary to reference. I attempted a for loop with lamda, but I'm pretty new to this so that didn't go well. I also tried to groupby account number and ticker before merging, but that didn't work either. The columns I'm trying to merge have the same datatype. I tried with non-float object and string.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Ticker', how = 'inner')
```

expected: (each account number may have 5 unique tickers)

```
A             B      C     D   
1             a    bond        500  
1             b   stock        100  
1             c    bond        250  
2             a    bond        300  
2             b    stock       400
```

what I get:

```
A             B      C     D   
1             a    bond        500  
1             a    bond        500  
1             a    bond        500  
2             a    bond        300  
2             a    bond        300
```

It seems to overwrite all the unique rows for the account number with the first row.

Comment: Can you provide examples for df1 and df2?

Comment: @iamchoosinganame yes, sorry about that.  I'm really sorry, I do not know how to format in this. Essentially, df1 has columns A,B, and D. df2 has columns B and C.
DF1:
[account number][Ticker][Market Value]  
12345 abcde  500
12345                   efghi    100
12345                   hijkl      250
55567                   abcde  300
55567                   efghi    150

df2:
[ticker][class]
abcde equity
fghij    bond
lmnop equity
qrstuv bond

I'm hoping to merge on the ticker, so that the class gets attached to the ticker in each row in df1

Comment: If you search for "formatting code in Stack Overflow" in your favourite search engine, you will find out how to format code/data.